# Android studio code completion no longer working

Tags: android, android-studio

I am on the latest version of Arch Linux. I recently encountered a bug in Android Studio where my code completion doesnt work. Originally the issue started with the code completion menu just showing up at the top of the screen instead of below my cursor, but now it doesnt show at all whatsoever. Here are some things I have tried to fix it:

1. Reinstalled Android Studio.
2. Invalidated my cache and restarted.
3. Manually deleted my cache.
4. Disabled and re-enabled code completion in the settings menu.

Nothing has worked so far. Do you guys have any suggestions on how I can fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried disabling Power Save mode, if its enabled? Its in File -> Power Save Mode.

Comment: It was already disabled. I enabled and disabled it again and nothing changed. EDIT: After doing that and restarting, it seems to have been fixed. Weird. Thank you for the help!

Comment: No problem! Happy to help! By the way it's my first accepted answer from someone else! Thank you too! 

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling 3rd party plugins that you might have installed.

I experienced similar behavior once I updated my AndroidStudio but after disabling **checkstyle** plugin, the code-completion started to work again.

Comment: I dont have any 3rd party plugins installed.